Tool to design and manage table inheritance but not ERD?
I am managing a lot of tables which have some kinds of derivation relationships between them, which looks like:

I said this is not ERD, is because that I am not managing entities, but just tables, there are no foreign keys or other constraints between these tables.
There are about 40 tables and 2k columns currently, and I am managing all of these manually, with a lot of hand writing and copying & pasting.
Which is slow and very error prone in my opinion, and I guess there will be more tables in the future.
So, is there a tool which could save me a little bit from this hell?
I want this tool to be able to visualize every table and relationships between tables and columns (I am currently design things in my brain and notepad)
It also needs to be able to generate CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO SELECT xxx statements automatically, or have some scripting abilities to assist me writing scripts to generate these statements. (to accelerate my work and avoid typos)
I can accept paid software if it has a reasonable price for personal use (I don't think my company will pay the price for me...)

If there's no foreign keys, in what format table relations are described?

@egor10_4 The relations are defined by human, you can think that there are some soft foreign keys exist between tables (e.g. any person in cleaned_person must also exist in raw_person), but these constraints are more like guidance rather than rules enforced by database (e.g. person has column case_id, but the data in case may not align with data in person). Besides, the DB I'm using does not support foreign keys, it's not a regular relational database.
